# creating a POST request in objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have implemented a REST based web service and used it to access data back in MySQL database.

I am using this framework to access the json data http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/

I have no problems in getting the content from this web service, but how can I put something in the database? Should I just make a special query string and have the php code in the backend to interpret this special keyword/query string as an insert to the database?

Comment: For the record, the latest versions of SBJSON/json-framework are available at GitHub: https://github.com/stig/json-framework

Comment: yes..I actually did use that version

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/). You can use that for everything from dumping pages to submitting data via POST or FORM.

Have fun :)

Comment: What is the problem with my initial proposal, to use a specific keywords and send it to the server and have it interpret it as an INSERT to the database instead of a GET or request to the page

Comment: No idea what's wrong with it. But your question's title was 'Creating a POST Request in objective-c'.

Comment: using the ASIHTTPRequest, then in my PHP code, I could just use an if statement and check if that is a POST?

Comment: Sorry, you'll need someone with web expertise for that. I just do client-side stuff. I let my friends deal with the servers. It should just be a normal POST implementation.

Answer (score 0):

POST is a HTTP method. Your web service should behave differently depending on the method used for the request, if you're implementing REST.

If you send a POST request, your web service should inspect the parameters and do what it needs to do.

What parameters you send and how is dependent on how you've written the web service. Ie. Is the web service expecting XML requests or JSON or URL parameters?

Comment: URL parameters should suffice